# Areas around windows and my desktop background show visual artifacts / distortions

Tags: 14.04, display, visual-artifacts

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04.02. My display gets distorted time and again. The distortion does not affect the full screen; it will be seen around dialog boxs or on the desktop in the background image area:

[image: lines and colour gradients around window]

My computer hardware is as follows,

```
Processor : Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P8600 @ 2.40GHz × 2 
Graphics  : Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2
Memory    : 3 GB (2,9 GiB shown)
Os- Type  : 32 Bit
```

Since I am a professional web designer and developer, this problem is really irritating for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the solution but the problem seems to be with the window decoration's shadows. Maybe you could install compizconfig-settings-manager and look where to disable them.

Comment: Thanks, it actually solve my problem. I turn off the Fading Windows effects and the problem seems to be gone.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: You could copy below how you solved it, and then mark it as solved so other people can find it.

Comment: Had similar problem on 16.04 LTS, with even more exotic patterns and colours around window edges and solved it with `CompizConfig Settings Manager`.

Answer (score 3):

I did not find out what actually caused the problem, but I've solved it by disabling *Fading Windows* under the **Effects** Menu using CompizConfig Settings Manager as suggested by [darent](https://askubuntu.com/users/6758/darent).